# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException maven

Tags: java, windows, maven, intellij-idea

In maven project (Intellij Idea) I've got `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` because I'm trying to create an object of a class which needs some external libraries.

```
public HelloWorldController() {
    service = new FileService();
    products.add(new Product("hello"));
    products.add(new Product("world"));
}
```

Everything works perfect without `service = new FileService();`, and here is FileService class:

```
public class FileService {

  public FileService()
  {
    irodsAccount = new IRODSAccount("192.168.6.128",1247,"rods","rods","","tempZone","demoResc");

    try {
        irodsFileSystem = new IRODSFileSystem();
    }
    catch (JargonException ex) {
    }
    try {
        this.dataTransferOps = irodsFileSystem.getIRODSAccessObjectFactory().getDataTransferOperations(irodsAccount);
    }
    catch (JargonException ex) {
    }

  }

  private String targetIrodsFileAbsolutePath;

  private IRODSAccount irodsAccount;

  private IRODSFileSystem irodsFileSystem;

  private TransferControlBlock transferControlBlock;

  private DataTransferOperations dataTransferOps = null;

  public IRODSFile getIRODSFileForPath(String irodsFilePath) throws Exception {
    if (irodsFilePath == null || irodsFilePath.isEmpty()) {
        throw new Exception("null or empty irodsFilePath");
    }
    return irodsFileSystem.getIRODSFileFactory(irodsAccount).instanceIRODSFile(irodsFilePath);
    }
}
```

`IRODSAccount`, `IRODSFileSystem` and other similar classes are got from external jars, which I connected to the project (added modules), but after running my project I have something like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.irods.jargon.core.exception.JargonException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:363)
    ... 62 more
```

Everything worked fine not in maven project with the same jars (I didn't get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`).
Adding a dependency to `pom.xml` file didn't solve my problem, I copied this from my previous project:

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.irods.jargon</groupId>
          <artifactId>jargon-httpstream</artifactId>
          <version>${jargon.version}</version>
      </dependency>
```

but, unfortunately, in lane `<version>${jargon.version}</version>` jargon.version is not recognized as a correct statement.

Comment: What if you remove the `<version>` tag? Maven will take a default version. Or declare a property with that name and the correct version number as value

Comment: You say you copied the dependency from a previous project. Do you know where the jar for the jargon-httpstream dependency resides? Maven will not magically find this jar unless it is hosted on Central which I don't believe it is.

Comment: Did you set ${jargon.version} in properties section?
<dependecy>
  <groupId>org.irods</groupId>
  <artifactId>jargon</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.3-beta1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @Pablo , unfortunately, the version is needed, I am trying to find a correct version number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <version>${jargon.version}</version>
```

Add the right the version in

```
   <properties>
    <jargon.version>2.4.1-SNAPSHOT<jargon.version>
    </properties>
```

in your pom file or directly

```
<version>2.4.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Comment: I changed version to 3.3.5-SNAPSHOT and it worked, that's a solution

Answer (score 0):

Because according to the [Maven documentation on the exec:exec](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html) goal you would need to have the <\classpath> stanza in your configuration in order to include the entire project module classpath.

However, it appears as though Maven is running the program with the fully (and properly) configured classpath for some reason.

In order to get to the bottom of the problem, I'd run Maven with the -X command line argument and carefully scan through the debug output until I found the exact command it runs. Then I'd try running it from the same directory, ensuring I am using the same Java installation and see if it works.